# How can a python unit test work with data files specified in setup.py package_data

Tags: python, pytest, setuptools, setup.py, python-importlib

I have json files which I would like to embed within my Python package.

I've read about using `package_data` in my `setup.py` and then using `importlib.resources` to access the data files at runtime (as documented [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) on the setuptools website.

What's confusing me is how to have this work when I'm running unit tests. A unit test won't have executed `setup.py` and so the json files won't be embedded for my code to read.

How do I write code which works when run both from a unit test and when running as an imported package?

A snippet of my setup.py is:

```
package_dir={"": "app"},
packages=find_packages(where="app"),
package_data={
    "mypackage": ["*.json"]
},
```

A module within mypackage is doing:

```
from importlib.resources import files
data_text = files("mypackage").joinpath("foo.json").read_text()
```

which produces the expected results when I'm consuming the package I've built (using setup.py), but when running from a unit test produces the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`

Comment: You need to make sure `mypackage` *is* a package. That may involve installing your package to a virtual environment before running the tests, or some other method of constructing a test fixture that makes your package available.

Comment: I'd argue that the package needs to be properly installed before running the tests. You want to run the tests in the situation that is the most representative of when the code will actually be running (which will imply it being installed, obviously, at least to me). -- There are tools that help with that, most notably *tox* (or *nox*). -- and of course, even a so-called "editable installation" should be good enough (even when the package is installed as editable, I think `importlib.resources` should still be able to find resources properly).

Comment: @sinoroc Depending on how you run your tests, there may be ways of setting the value of `sys.path`, the module's `__package__` attribute, etc, that basically makes the code "look" installed, but I agree that actually installing the package is usually simplest.